# How to delete users on DHIS2 2.18

Tags: dhis2

Please can someone help me. I created a user in DHIS2 version 2.18 but now i want to delete/remove that user; every time i click 'remove' it is taking forever.

Please help me

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting or DHIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a problem here in that users cannot be deleted if they are associated with other objects in the system, such as chart favorites, dashboards, data elements etc. The only options currently is to delete such relationships in the database directly, or to disable the user by clicking on "disable" in the user context menu.